# verbose_name для вычислимого поля модели Django

Tags: python, django, django-model

Есть следующая модель. В полях, которые я указываю собственноручно verbose_name прописывается понятным образом. А как прописать verbose_name для поля которое является вычислимым? В данном случае days_worked.

```
class Employee(models.Model):
name = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name="ФИО")
date_of_start = models.DateField(verbose_name="Дата оформления")
position = models.ForeignKey("Position", on_delete=models.PROTECT, verbose_name="Должность")
department = models.ForeignKey("Department", on_delete=models.PROTECT, verbose_name="Подразделение")

def __str__(self):
    return self.name

@property
def days_worked(self):
    days_worked = datetime.now().date() - self.date_of_start
    return days_worked.days
```

Comment: А действительно ли требуется это прописывать именно в модели? Может, в ModelAdmin тоже подойдёт?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по всему verbose_name для @property не может быть установлено, но вместо него можно использовать short_description:

```
days_worked.fget.short_description = 'блаблабла'
```

Comment: Sergey Tatarincev, да, спасибо большое, работает. Учту такую тонкость настройки)